# Search and Replace text in file .net 2.0.What Am I missing?

Tags: c#

I have an xml file with some placeholder if you like.I need to read it and searchReplace the placeholders.Each placeholder is unique.
I thought of using this method rather than xpath as I have never used it and the xml file is very deep and complex.Thought reading in a string and then replace should do the trick.
Am I missing something obvious?

Why is below not searching and replacing?

```
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            content.Replace("FirstReplace", "test1");
            content.Replace("SecondReplace", "test2");
            content.Replace("ThirdReplace", "test3");
            content.Replace("FourthReplace", "test4");
            content.Replace("FifthReplace", "test5");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(content);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions

Comment: +1 for using String.Replace as the simplest approach that would work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because strings are immutable in .NET and the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method returns a new string instance as result. It does not modify the original string. So:

```
content = content
    .Replace("FirstReplace", "test1")
    .Replace("SecondReplace", "test2")
    .Replace("ThirdReplace", "test3")
    .Replace("FourthReplace", "test4")
    .Replace("FifthReplace", "test5");
```

Of course if you have lots of replacing to do in tight loops, many string allocations could start to hurt the performance and it is where [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) comes handy:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(content);
    .Replace("FirstReplace", "test1")
    .Replace("SecondReplace", "test2")
    .Replace("ThirdReplace", "test3")
    .Replace("FourthReplace", "test4")
    .Replace("FifthReplace", "test5");
content = sb.ToString();
```

or to simplify your code a little and get read of those stream readers/writers:

```
File.WriteAllText(
    filePath, 
    File.ReadAllText(path)
        .Replace("FirstReplace", "test1")
        .Replace("SecondReplace", "test2")
        .Replace("ThirdReplace", "test3")
        .Replace("FourthReplace", "test4")
        .Replace("FifthReplace", "test5")
);
```

Comment: @Dimitrov That worked a treat and very simple.There is no dispose involved here is there?On another note what is the fastest way to read  a directory with thousand of files inside.Only interested in their name.

Comment: @user231465, in the second example the Dispose method is internally handled by the WriteAllText and ReadAllText methods so you don't have to worry about it. As far as your second question is concerned, I don't quite understand what do you mean by ` read a directory with thousand of files inside`. Files are normally stored on a file system.

Comment: @Dimitrov Sorry for been not clear.Forget the question about the folders.In your example with the StringBuilder is that inside a using statement as x my question?

Comment: @user231465, yes, because the content variable is available inside this using statement. But it could also be used with the WriteAllText and ReadAllText methods.